MongoDB audit with EventListener specific document only
On my Spring Boot application with MongoDB I need to audit collections and I'm trying to configure it with EventListeners. I implemented it as follows and it works, but I'm forced to check the instance type, while I would prefer to do it via configuration. I expected that AfterSaveEvent<Playlist> would be enough, but when I save the event with playlistAudRepository.save(playlistAud); it gets caught by the listener again. I also tried to annotate method @EventListener(Playlist.class) but it does not capture events anymore. What am I doing wrong?
@EventListener
public void handleAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<Playlist> event) {
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Playlist) {
        Playlist playlist = (Playlist) event.getSource();
        PlaylistAud playlistAud = new PlaylistAud(playlist);
        playlistAud.setAuditType(playlist.getVersion() == 0 ? AuditType.INITIAL : AuditType.UPDATE);
        playlistAudRepository.save(playlistAud);
    }
}


CDC will always capture any operations happened on the collection, i would encourage to filter on specific attribute value or null check if needed @EventListener(condition = "#event.source.someProperty == 'desiredValue'") or @EventListener(condition = "#event.source.someProperty != null")
